# Drupal 7 server crash after 20-30 concurrent users

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, drupal-7

We've just started our first **drupal (7.22)** site on our cloud server and everything went well until we reached 20-30 concurrent users and then suddenly the whole server crashed. We weren't even able to reach the server through terminal at all. Only thing we could do is to reboot the server at our hosting's client area then everything went fine again until a certain number of users and the whole problem started again and again.

Before the first crash, one of our admin got a MySQL error message so my only thought is that our MySQL settings are not well configured to a Drupal 7 site.

Error message:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/drupal/includes/lock.inc).
```

Server:

```
Ubuntu 11.04
CPU 2.1 GHz
Memory 1128MB
```

Did anybody meet with this kind of problem?

Comment: Have you any additional information, like mysql error logs? This problem can have several causes on mysql side. So more info would be nice.

Comment: Directly from the logs you can´t see a problem which leads to the above described effects. Have you already tried using an tcp-socket rather than a unix-socket to connect to your db?